# Why does Excel display my information like this in print preview?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

Here's what it looks like in regular mode:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/J3yyufE.png]

And here's what it looks like in print preview:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/nZKsBO1.png]

I'm very new to Excel, have been having many similar hiccups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try resizing the column to be a tad bit bigger.  This should fix error.
If you notice in your standard view the text on the one row wraps down.  On the print view it does not.  This generally means the text needs to be a little bit smaller or the column needs to be a little bit wider.

Comment: It doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Change it a bit more then. @Iraedei n.p. I removed it ;-)

Comment: adjust the column width on the original until A20 is all on one line or you could even make it smaller so that two words are wrapped to the second line.

Comment: @Iraedei, I've decided to make the text 1px smaller, and it's working out for me in more ways than one. Thank you.

Comment: @Iraedei Nice solution, glad it worked for you Swamp85.

Answer (score 0):

#### Why does Excel display my information like this in print preview?

- Excel’s normal screen display doesn’t always match the print appearance;
  in particular, in terms of the size (width) of text relative to the size of cells. 
  I’m not sure *exactly* why this is, but I guess it has to do with the fact that
  printers typically have higher resolution than monitors (600dpi is common for printers),
  and so, when you display characters on the screen,
  it’s impossible to get the exact right size without using fractional pixels. 
  You can demonstrate this for yourself by typing `lllllllllllllll…`
  (enough lower-case `L`s to fill the cell width) into a cell,
  and then adjusting the magnification (zoom).

  So (**tl;dr**), part of what’s happening is that
  “Looks like a professional paper in literary studies” fits all on one line in column `A`
  when you print (or preview) the file, but not on screen (at 100% magnification).
- And the other thing is that the default vertical alignment in cells in Excel is “Bottom”.

#### How can I fix it?

There are several ways.

- As other people have suggested, you could make column `A` wide enough to fit
  “Looks like a professional paper in literary studies” all on one line on the screen
  (at 100% magnification).
- As you suggested, change cell `A20` to a smaller font.
- Make row 20 shorter (i.e., less tall) – tall enough to hold just one line of text instead of two. 
  This will result in the word “studies” not being visible on the screen
  (except when you click on cell `A20` and then look in the formula box), but it will print nicely.
- Click on cell `A20` and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>
  (not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>). 
  Go to the “Alignment” tab and set the “Vertical” drop-down box to “Top”. 
  That will make the print preview look like this:

  [image]

  i.e., there will still be a blank line,
  but it will be *below* “Looks like a professional paper in literary studies”.