# Display on excel does not match with Print Preview

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing

In Row 18 on display, just 6 rows but on print preview, it became 7 rows. This case I got after an update of Microsoft Windows, I tested on the other PC which was not updated, and the display and print preview matched.
[image]

[image]

It's a big problem to me because all templates are like that. It also appears in case that the content in 1 cell - wrap text, I use auto fit row, it's fit with what's show on display but on print preview is not.

I found a way to fix, but it's not good by use alignment: Top
[Why does Excel display my information like this in print preview?](https://superuser.com/questions/789843/why-does-excel-display-my-information-like-this-in-print-preview)

Comment: Sorry, I edited

Comment: Unfortunately Excel doesn't manage layout perfectly, and there is no really good solution for that. If that's really an issue for you, then your only option is to copy the table into another program (e.g. Word) and print it from there.

Comment: I use this form daily ok before windows has a big update Anniversary, I test on other PC not updated windows it's skill good.
I'm got angry with microsoft, my job be stucked by this problem.
Thank you

Comment: then only chance is to reinstall the update:( And maybe complain on Microsoft's sites.

Comment: I'm uninstalling 2 update of excel (may be plus update of Office) and finding a site to complain. Could you give me a link. Thank you

Comment: go to Microsoft.com and look for feedback. Or just google for it. I don't have any link.

Comment: I found a thing that when use excel online every things show on web match exactly with print preview not as Excel on PC. Microsoft suck.. :(